# Finding a typoscript code on big pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, objectbrowser

There's a meta tag with charset ISO and I need to change it to utf8. I browsed through templates and configs, and cannot find the meta tag where it is set. Also I tried to override it with:

```
config.metaCharset = utf-8
```

and other config settings on that page without any success.

What's the best way to find a section of Typoscript I'm searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not found but it was possible to **convert the files** with broken charakters **to the charset in this meta tag** (ISO-8859-1). so the characters working now without any changes in the config and/or charsets.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding parameter could be also specifed through :

```
config.additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
config.renderCharset = utf-8
```

Use TypoScript Object Browser to inspect the elements on the page in question.

Comment: i already did... searched the whole page with object browser for this meta tag also in the templates. this tag seems like its magically appearing there oO whereelse this tag could be set?

Comment: Probably, it's hardcoded in Your HTML templates ? Check localconf.pfp values also, probably it comes from Install Tool.

Comment: No sorry :( not in HTML and also not in localconf.php

Comment: Check if $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset'] is set to 'utf-8'